# How can I configure less to recognize Ctrl-Left, Ctrl-Right

Tags: terminal, less

The `less` manpage says you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> to move the cursor by one word when performing line editing (e.g. entering a search string):

```
^LEFTARROW [ ESC-b or ESC-LEFTARROW ]
     (That is, CONTROL and LEFTARROW simultaneously.)  Move the
     cursor one word to the left.
```

When I try this, it instead enters the printed representation of the control sequence my terminal sent. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> enters `ESC[1;5D` and Ctrl-Right enters `ESC[1;5C`.

My terminal is configured to send `^[[1;5D` and `^[[1;5C` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd>, respectively, and I put this in my `~/.inputrc` so Readline would perform word-wise jumps when I'm in the shell (Bash),

```
# Ctrl-Left
"\033[1;5D": backward-word
# Ctrl-Right
"\033[1;5C": forward-word
```

Presumably `less` is expecting some different control sequence? I'm a little hesitant to change the escape sequences my terminal is sending just to satisfy `less`, for fear it would trip up Vim or Readline, but I'm willing to give it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure less's key bindings so that the sequence `\e[1;5D` runs `word-left` and `\e[1;5C` runs `word-right.

In the file `~/.lesskey`, add

```
#line-edit
\e[1;5D    word-left
\e[1;5C    word-right
```

If there is already a `#line-edit` section, add the requisite lines.

Then run [`lesskey`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lesskey). This companion program transforms `~/.lesskey` (in human-readable syntax) into the binary format `~/.less` that `less` uses.

Comment: Slight correction: at least on my version of Less, I had to put these bindings in the `line-edit` section (rather than `command`), or lesskey would complain.